# Are there still no mission updates for Perseverance like there are for Curiosity?

Tags: mars, nasa, curiosity, perseverance

[Mission updates for the Mars Curiosity rover](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/mission-updates/?month=8&year=2012) in the first months of the mission starting in August 2012 happened almost every day with detailed information about drive planning, the use of the different instruments, choosing certain targets etc.
(Why) isn't there such a site for the Perseverance rover ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since August 4, 2021 there is a [blog for the Mars Perseverance rover](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/mission/status/), just like there is for Curiosity.

The first installment of the blog on August 4 was written by Ken Farley, Project Scientist at Caltech and Jennifer Trosper, Project Manager at NASA/JPL, and ended with the following sentence:

"This blog is an opportunity for our team members to share their discoveries and experiences contributing to this amazing  undertaking."

Answer (score 2):

It appears that they are doing so, but on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/NASAPersevere) and [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/NASAPersevere).

Comment: the linked source in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51107/12102) mentions how things are different during COVID019 for Perseverance folks at JPL